# How many confirmations does a transaction needs to be included in a snapshot?

Tags: altcoin, electrum

I bought bitcoin to participate in bitcoin hex. I sent my bitcoin to the electrum wallet and it has over 500 confirmations. Bitcoin Hex will snapshot bitcoin and I want my bitcoin address to be included in the snapshot. How can I find out if it will be included in the snapshot?

Comment: It looks like a scam to me.

Comment: That's the samething I thought. But I found out you dont have to give them money. So it cant be a scam.

Comment: @Luke101 scams extract value in ways that are not always obvious